# Windows 7 Explorer - number of undoable actions (undo levels)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, undo

Could it be M$ changed that number from 10 in previous Windows versions to **1 (ONE)**?

Create a new folder. Create 11 new documents of whatever type is handy in your context menu. Delete them **one after the other**. Now undo each deletion using the "Undo" command or CTRL + Z.

**In Win7 x64, I can only undo the last deletion.** After that, only "Redo" is available from the menu.

In Windows XP, I can undo 10 deletions (just checked & counted), like it's supposed to be since Win95. (See Microsoft article [here)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/171296)

If this is normal behavior for Win 7, I'd appreciate a hint at how to change it - registry hacks or third party utilities, no matter.

P.S. I'm running with [Classic Shell and Classic Explorer](http://classicshell.net/) installed.